# I want to divide a file according to a specific word, and based on this word I want the above line, then puted in newfile.txt

Tags: python, search, text, split, line

I want to divide a file based on a specific word, and based on this word if he finds it, I want the line above it, then puts the line above it and the word with the content in a file, and it stops when he finds the line above the specified word ? plz help 
this is mu code :

```py
import collections
import itertools
import sys

count = 0
done = False

with open("file".txt") as in_file:
    before = collections.deque(maxlen=3)
    while not done: 
        with open(f"newfile{count}.txt", "w") as out_file:
             while not done:
                try:
                    line = next(in_file).strip() 
                except StopIteration:
                    done = True
                    break
                if "X-IronPort-RCPT-TO" in line:
                    out_file.write(line)
                    before.append('\n')

                    break
                else:

                    out_file.writelines(before)
                    out_file.write('\n')
                    out_file.write(line)

        count += 1
```

Comment: What does your code do at the moment? How does it fail?

Comment: It only takes the exact sentence and the line above it without the content below it

Answer (score 0):

not sure if that what you want

```
with open("file".txt") as in_file:
    lines = in_file.readlines():
    for l in range(len(lines)):
        if "X-IronPort-RCPT-TO" in lines[l]:
            line_above = lines[l-1]
```